# dark/light mode in react-native using nativewind

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, darkmode

I use nativewind(tailwind) in rect-native. I'm working on dark/light mode. I want to do it in the nicest possible way, clean code. 
I want `<Text className='text-white dark:text-black'>` to be for example`<Text className='text-textColor'>` instead of this.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary': '#fffff',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I have one possible solution that works but it is not the best possible solution.

```js
const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useColorScheme();
  const colors = {
    text: colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black',
  };
  <Text className={`text-${colors.text}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to know that tailwind do not accept interpolation on class names. For example:

```
<Text className={`text-${colors.text}`}>
```

[Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth) is how you can fix that.

---

Now, answering the question, according to the documentation you can use the `dark:` variant and it will be controlled by `useColorScheme()`.

> If you're using `expo`, you need to modify your `app.json` changing the `userInterfaceStyle` to automatic:
>
> ###### app.json
>
> ```json
> {
>   "expo": {
>     "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
>   }
> }
> ```

To manipulate theme's state, you could use a simple `useState/Context API` (not persisted) or `AsyncStorage/MMKV/...` (persisted state). After that, you can use `dark:` variant in that way:

```
import { Pressable, Text } from "react-native"
import { useColorScheme } from "nativewind";

function App() {
  const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Pressable
      className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-neutral-100 dark:bg-neutral-900"
      onPress={toggleColorScheme}>
      <Text className="text-black dark:text-white">
        {`Try clicking me! ${colorScheme === "dark" ? "" : ""}`}
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

> The base of this example was extracted from the [documentation](https://www.nativewind.dev/core-concepts/dark-mode)

I hope to help you.

Answer (score -2):

just try this

```
const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useColorScheme();
  const colors = {
    text: colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'text-white' : 'dark:text-black',
  };
  <Text className={colors.text}>
```